# Bootstrap dropdowns menus appearing behind other DIV's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.6
So I'm using their 'dropdown-menu' on my 'top-box' div to display submenu.
But for some reason 'dropdown-menu' are appearing behind the 'header-brand' DIV on my site.
I added z-index to my CSS, but still doesn't seem to do anything, Please help.

**Here is My Project URL: [Click Here](http://45.114.142.104/design/demo/arc/dealer/)**

```
<header id="header">

    <!-- BEGIN TOP BAR -->
    <div class="top-box animatedq fadeInDownq">
        <div class="left-bar">
            <ul class="list-inline top-contact-info">
                <li><i class="fa fa-mobile-phone"></i> 24X7 Contact : +91 9830556230</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right-bar">
            <ul class="list-inline top-menu-items" role="navigation">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> Create Wallet</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> User Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Agent Login</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END TOP BAR -->

    <!-- BEGIN BRAND(COMPANY NAME & LOGO) -->
    <div class="header-brand">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="social-icons">
            <ul class="icons">
                <li><a href="#" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="google Plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Skype"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Vimeo"><i class="fa fa-vimeo"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END BRAND(COMPANY NAME & LOGO) -->
</header>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.top-box .submenu {
    z-index: 9999999999 !important;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: The problem (no solution here, sorry) is your .topbox { overflow: hidden; } Anything you put in this div will get cut off if when it goes over the bounds. Of course, when you remove it you'll have a whole new mess on your hands.

Comment: You could probably just remove `overflow: hidden;` and use a set height instead `height: 31px` and things would probably be fine.

Comment: But it hide the content on mobile view @ ippi

Comment: Ah, I should have realized. Remove the height and go with @jpedroribeiro's answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned, remove `overflow:hidden` from `.top-box` to stop clipping the content and add the class `clearfix` to clear the floats of the inner divs.

```
<div class="top-box animatedq fadeInDownq clearfix">
```